# Error Code 1172 in procedures to insert data

Tags: mysql

I have three tables students [id (PK, NN, AI), name], courses [id (PK, NN, AI), name] and studentCourses [students.id (PK, FK), courses.id (PK, FK)]

I'm trying to code the example of this video in mysql:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cEfjYynwooE&list=PLfh-ZUr1u03oCF23J3YfWSyLT_NJ0nGA4&index=29&t=81s

This is my code

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE insertData(IN studentName_param varchar(45), IN courseName_param varchar(45))
BEGIN

    SET @StudentId = '';
    SET @CourseId = '';

    SELECT COALESCE(Id, 0) INTO @StudentId FROM Students WHERE StudentName = studentName_param;
    IF @StudentId = 0 THEN INSERT INTO Students (StudentName) VALUES (studentName_param);

    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @StudentId FROM Students;
    END IF;
    

    SELECT COALESCE(Id, 0) INTO @CourseId FROM Courses WHERE CourseName = courseName_param;
    IF @CourseId = 0 THEN INSERT INTO Courses (CourseName) VALUES (courseName_param);

    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @CourseId FROM Courses;
    END IF;
      

    INSERT INTO StudentCourses (StudentID, CoursesID) VALUES (@StudentId, @CourseId);
    
END //
DELIMITER ;

CALL insertData ('Joe', 'Photoshop') //no problem
CALL insertData ('Joe', 'Actionscript') //Error Code: 1172. Result consisted of more than one row
```

Any idea? Any help?

Comment: Error suggest you are selecting a resultset into a variable (which you cannot do) - I cannot tell which select is the problem and suggest you comment out until you find it. AND please add sample data as text to the question.

Comment: Video is not applicable. Provide CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts with sample data in textual form and desired result for this data with the explanations.

Comment: and quote the full error within the post, not just a paraphrase in the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scheme needs `StudentName` and `CourseName` columns to be defined as UNIQUE in according tables (if not there is no way to distinguish rows with equal values). If not then fix this (do it once) by

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx ON Students (StudentName);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx ON Courses (CourseName);
```

---

Then:

1. Insert `StudentName` and `CourseName` into according tables unconditionally using `INSERT IGNORE`

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO Students (StudentName) VALUES (studentName_param);
INSERT IGNORE INTO Courses (CourseName) VALUES (courseName_param);
```

2. Insert data into link table using

```
INSERT INTO StudentCourses (StudentID, CoursesID)
SELECT s.id, c.id
FROM Students s
CROSS JOIN Courses c
WHERE s.StudentName = studentName_param
  AND c.CourseName = courseName_param;
```

You may combine this into one SP:

```
DELIMITER //;
CREATE PROCEDURE insertData( IN studentName_param varchar(45), 
                             IN courseName_param varchar(45) )
BEGIN
    INSERT IGNORE INTO Students (StudentName) VALUES (studentName_param);
    INSERT IGNORE INTO Courses (CourseName) VALUES (courseName_param);
    INSERT INTO StudentCourses (StudentID, CoursesID)
        SELECT s.id, c.id
        FROM Students s
        CROSS JOIN Courses c
        WHERE s.StudentName = studentName_param
          AND c.CourseName = courseName_param;
END//;
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Akina.

Solution totally different but it works fine.

---

I could solved my solution:

1. StudentName and CourseName, defined as unique as you suggested
2. I have changed 'Last_Insert_ID' by 'MAX(Id)'.

i know that my solution is not perfect, i'll try to do best just for fun

THANK YOU ALL